# Probability of washing dishes

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if my answer to this question is correct.

A, B and C live in an apartment together. A gets up in the morning before B and C is up last. First, to the kitchen, A encounters a sink full of dirty dishes and washes them with probability $pA=1/2$. Similarly, after A has left, on encountering dirty dishes, B washes them with probability $pB=1/3$. Likewise, C washes them with probability  $pC=1/4$.

a) What is the probability that the dishes get done?

b) If the dishes get done, what is the probability that C washed them?

A) P[dishes are done] = $(1/2) * (1/3) * (1/4) = 1/24$

B) Use conditional probability

P[C washed dishes] = P[dishes are done] * P[A washed dishes] * P[Bwashed dishes]

P[C washed dishes] = $(1/24) * (1/2) * (1/3) = 1/144$

Comment: A)  How can the probablility that the dishes are done at all be less than the probability that they are done by A?  Imagine A gets up and does the dishes with the probability of 1/2 and then leaves.  Then image a meteor hits the apartment and everyone dies.  The probability that the dishes were done is 1/2.  Now imagine that the meteor didn't hit and B and C wake up.  You are saying the probabilty that the dishes getting done without B or C possibly  doing them, is *greater* than if B and C might actually do them?  That's not possible, is it?

Comment: Does that mean that the probability of all the dishes getting washed is the sum of all the individual probabilities?

Comment: If everyone dies, the probability still exists in space? I am also not sure a person washes dirty dishes either partially or fully.

Comment: "Does that mean that the probability of all the dishes getting washed is the sum of all the individual probabilities?"  No.  I'm just pointing out that if $A$ has a $1/2$ probability then $A$ or $B$ or $C$ must have a greater than 1/2 probability.  So getting $1/24$ is clearly not correct.  As for what *is* correct.  Well, we can't just guess. mulitply?  No? Add? No? Take the exponents?  No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) What is the probability that the dishes get done?

1 - "Probability that the dishes does not get washed by anyone"

and

"Probability that the dishes does not get washed by anyone" = (1 - pA)*(1-pB)*(1-pC)

b) If the dishes get done, what is the probability that C washed them?

(1-pA)*(1-pB)*pC / (  pA + (1-pA)*pB + (1-pA)*(1-pB)*pC  )

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment of guest, giving a formula,
the answer works out to be $\frac34$ and $\frac19$, in that order.
(Also, the denominator of his second formula simplifies to $1-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$.)